# Can jquery click event simular mousewheel up and down?

Tags: jquery, click, mousewheel

Can jquery click event simulate mousewheel up and down?  I tried to reach some function link: click up arrow, simulate mousewheel up. click down arrow,  simulate mousewheel down.

```
<a id="up">up</a>
<a id="down">down</a>


$('#up').click(){
   $('#left').bind('mousewheel',up); //scroll div#left to top 
});
$('#down').click(){
   $('#left').bind('mousewheel',down); //scroll div#left to bottom
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#up').click(function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({scrollTop: '-=100'}, 300); 
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    $('div').stop().animate({scrollTop: '+=100'}, 300); 
});
```

This is an interesting way of doing it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9ze6/

Answer (score 0):

`.bind` does not simulate an event - use `.trigger` and/or `.triggerHandler` for that. Also, note that plain jQuery does not support mousewheel events - you need a plugin for that. See http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/mousewheel. But maybe `.scroll` will be good enough for you.